# Screen in crontab

Tags: bash, scripts, php, screen, cron

I'm trying to run 9 screens windows by crontab, and then, run some codes (basically the same for all of them), but they don't work.
The code runs all of 9 screens, but run code only on the first.
Aah, I'm doing all of this on a for loop.

Here is my code:

sudo crontab -e:

```
01 * * * * bash /path/to/create_screen.sh
02 * * * * bash /path/to/execute_command_screen.sh
```

create_screen.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

pkill -15 screen

for i in {0..9}
  do
    screen -dmS "name_screen$i"
  done
```

Until here, they works perfectly, after this, it falls on the problem mentioned above.

execute_command_screen.sh:

```
for i in {0..9}
  do
    screen -S "name_screen$i" -X stuff 'cd /path/to/script/to/execute'`echo -ne '\015'`
    screen -S "name_screen$i" -X stuff 'php script_to_run.php'`echo -ne '\015'`
    sleep 1
  done
```

I put the code in 2 scripts because, in only one, they don't execute.
And yes, the script that I'm trying to execute on all 9 screens is a php :).

Anyone can help me?
Thanks